# Is there any way to opt out of dark mode for widget in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios-darkmode

The application that I'm working on right now doesnt support dark mode yet. I was able to opt out of dark mode in the application by adding a key in the plist. But, The widget still becomes dark when I turn on Dark Mode in iOS 13. Is there any way to opt out of Dark Mode for widget too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it really so hard to make just the widget respond to dark mode?

Comment: `.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;`

Comment: I tried overriding the useruInterfaceStyle. But, only the font color is reverting back to what it has to be when it's in light theme. But, the blurred background of the widget is still black. Is there any way to change that too.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to override the [InterfaceStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/3238086-overrideuserinterfacestyle) in the Controller of your widget like in the example below:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light    
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this in my code. But, only the font color is reverting back to what it has to be in light theme. But, the blurred background of the widget is still black. Is there any way to change that too.

Comment: In that case I guess the best option for you is to adapt your widget to dark mode. The Apple Human Interface Guidelines are recommending to not change the blurred background view. Check out the the subheading Avoid customizing the background of a widget.
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/extensions/widgets/

Comment: Thank you @Lukas. I'll look into it